# Grails behavior method AddTo*

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I'm an instability in my addTo* method which I have a record that constantly have to make the relationship information in one instance . The problem is that when I place multiple inserts in a short time , they cease to be persisted in the database and not after a they return , they are simply discarded time.

My simple class is ' Occurrence ' and ' Monitoring ' , whenever I make a call I have to register it and it occurred on and after 2 consecutive records the 3rd no longer persists in the database and I lose the record .

```
Class Occurrence implements Serializable{
...
hasMany = [accompaniments: Monitoring]
...
}

Class Monitoring implements Serializable{
...
belongsTo = [occurrence : Occurrence]
...
}
```

Have the controller looks like this:

```
def regMonitoring(Long id){

        def chamadoInstance = Occurrence.get(id)

        if (!chamadoInstance) {
            flash.message = message(code: 'default.not.found.message', args: [message(code: 'Occurrence .label', default: 'Occurrence '), id])
            return
        }

        chamadoInstance.status = StatusChamado.findByCodigo("MOV") 

        if (!chamadoInstance.save(flush: true)) {
            render(view: "editMonitoring", model: [chamadoInstance: chamadoInstance])
            return
        }


        def mov = chamadoService.regMonitoring("") //returns an instance of Customer with preset output values ​​.

        chamadoInstance.addToAccompaniments (mov) 

        redirect(action: "showChamado", id: chamadoInstance.id)


    }
```

Comment: Add chamadoInstance.save(flush: true) after you addToAccompaniments.

Comment: Solved the problem! Thank you! I realized that before this change, the first time it was instantiated and after the third instance was not persisted. I wonder why this happens?

Comment: Glad it solved the issue (added as an answer so you can accept and upvote it).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add in a save of your domain instance after you add to the collection.

```
chamadoInstance.addToAccompaniments (mov) 
chamadoInstance.save(flush: true)
```

This should solve the issue.

Comment: I realized that before this change, the first time it was instantiated and after the third instance was not persisted. I wonder why this happens?

Comment: Without doing some serious debugging of the way GORM handles that I don't know off the top of my head. I suspect it has something to do with the way Hibernate caches the instances.